# Smarty code to normal php

Tags: php, smarty

How do i change this code back to normal i really don't know how to change it back

```
$template = new Smarty;
//assign to smarty
$template->assign('username', stripslashes($username));
$template->assign('email_address', stripslashes($email_address));
$template->assign('step', 1);
```

so how can i change this to normal php i don't know how i should assign these values with normal php

i already tried this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$step = 1;
```

this doesn't work

Comment: what is unnormal php? :)

Comment: Seems like normal PHP to me..

Comment: In Smarty, this is assigning variable value to templates. In your php code its a POST value assign to a value. No similarity between two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty assigns variables to view. It really depends on your project structure. If it is MVC then you should change your VIEW class. If it is not and variables are visible within project then you will have access to `$username` and `$email_address` and you can remove your smarty code. To give you more specific answer you need provide more details on how your project manages views etc.

```
$username = stripslashes($username);
$email_address = stripslashes($email_address);
echo $username.$email_adress;
```

Voila you have access which by the way you have already had.

Smarty is very good system of templates. Think twice about changing it. I work with smarty for a long time and it's very good.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$step = 1;
```

append next code to your code

```
$template->assign(get_defined_vars());
```